# Implementing the Iterable interface

Tags: java, interface, iterator, iterable

I just found this exam question in an old exam paper and am readying myself for an upcoming exam. I cannot figure it out :

The following depicts a contrived partial class which implements the Iterable interface. The only purpose of this class is to provide a method to iterate over the attribute `things.`

There are two things we need to fill in in the class to finish it. Here is the class

```
private class PartialIterableClass /*FILL IN */ {
   private String[] things;
   public PartialIterableClass( String[] things ){
      this.things = things;
   }
   /*FILL IN 2*/
}
```

I am guessing it should be something similar to :

```
private class PartialIterableClass implements Iterable<PrivateIterableClass> {
   private String[] things;
   public PartialIterableClass( String[] things ){
      this.things = things;
   }
   public Iterator<PartialIterableClass> iterator( ){
   return new Iterator<PartialIterableClass>( ) {

   }
   }
}
```

I'm not really sure how to flesh out an answer to this question though, can anybody help?

Comment: If it implements the `Comparable` interface, shouldn't it have a `compare()` method?

Comment: your solution ignores the question in favour of the classname, you should implement Comparable<String> instead.

Comment: How "old" is the exam paper where you read this ? I'm asking because it's very likely that it was written before Java 5 was released (therefore, before the word "iterable" meant the `java.util.Iterable` interface to a Java developer).

Comment: Sorry, the question is fixed, I was looking at the wrong one whilst typing.

Comment: @Loadmaster: No, it shouldn't ! But it should have a `compareTo()` method instead ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `Iterator` must implement all the methods from the `Iterator` interface in order to encapsulate the iteration logic.

In your case, it will have to hold the current iteration index in the array. You can look at [`ArrayIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/ArrayIterator.html) from commons-collections

Comment: I am confused, how would you go about implementing this in my case?

Comment: exactly as I said :) hold the current iteration index. commons-collections is open source, so take a look at the code there.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would probably be to create a `new ArrayList<String>()` populated with the values in `things`, and return the result of a call to its `.iterator()` method. That's certainly what I'd do in a situation with limited time (like an exam), and quite likely what I'd do in a real-world scenario, just to keep things simple.

You could write your own `ArrayIterator` class, or use one from various libraries you can find around the web, but it seems like that would add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class PartialIterableClass implements Iterable<String> {
    private String[] things;
    public PartialIterableClass( String[] things ){
        this.things = things;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return Arrays.asList(things).iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are converting the array into a temporary list in the memory just to iterate it ?!

Comment: There's little "conversion" going on with `Arrays.asList()`. It just decorates the original array with a `List` view, using a private helper class `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`.

Comment: You are basically creating a List of references to the array, which are also an extra space has to be allocated. Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Comment: You lost me at "List of *references to the array*", but we should probably move this conversation to chat if we are to go on with it. For now, I'll just accept your down-vote stoically. :)

Comment: Creating a list to get the iterator is the obvious answer that no one wants, you already know that it's not a real solution and that it can be costly if the array size is big. And I don't like rabbit-holes so I wouldn't chat on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayIterator`, or build your own iterator like this:

```
package arrayiterator;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class ArrayIterator_int
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] arr = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

        ArrayIterator_int iterator = new ArrayIterator_int(arr);

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("  " + iterator.next());
        }
    }

    private int cursor;
    private final int [] array;
    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public ArrayIterator_int (int [] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.cursor = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext ()
    {
        boolean hasNext = false;
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            hasNext = ((this.cursor+1) < this.array.length);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
            return hasNext;
        }

    }

    public int next () throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        int next = 0;
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            next = this.array[++this.cursor];
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
            return next;
        }
    }

    public int read () throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        int read = 0;
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            read = this.array[this.cursor];
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
            return read;
        }
    }

    public void write (int newVal) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {
        lock.lock();

        try
        {
            this.array[this.cursor] = newVal;
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```