# for-each loop can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java

The following code doesn't work. What's wrong with this code? Compiler complains in the for loop that `NumberList` isn't a `Iterable` class.

What kind of class can be used in for-each loop? How to make `NumberList` iterable? I tried making `NumberList implement Iterable`, but it doesn't seem to work because I don't know how to define the Iterator properly.

If someone could demonstrate how to make this code work, or link me to a tutorial that'd be great.

```
public class Test{
    public class NumberList{
        private int numItems;
        private Number[] numbers;

        public NumberList(int size){
            this.numbers = new Number[size];
            this.numItems=0;
        }

        public void add(Number n){
            this.numbers[this.numItems++]=n;
        }
    }

    public void printPairs() {
        ArrayList<Integer> num=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        NumberList numbers = new NumberList(50);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(6);

        for(Number n1: numbers){
            System.out.println(n1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you define your own list, and not using an ArrayList?

Comment: First, definitely use the list that comes with the JDK. No use defining your own as the previous commenter said. But if you want to fix your code, the compiler gave you the answer. Just implement Iterable and fill out the required methods.

Comment: There are other questions on SO about ways to implement Iterable, including [Implementing the Iterable interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050379/implementing-the-iterable-interface).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumberList does not implement Iterable. As far as the compiler is concerned its just any other class.

You need to do something like this

```
public class NumberList implements Iterable<Number> {

    private int numItems;
    private Number[] numbers;

    public NumberList(int size) {
        this.numbers = new Number[size];
        this.numItems = 0;
    }

    public void add(Number n) {
        this.numbers[this.numItems++] = n;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Number> iterator() {
        return Arrays.asList(numbers).subList(0, numItems).iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer is fine, but illustrates the futility of this exercise: All you have is a thin delegation layer adding no value.

Comment: And the answer is not really fine, since the iterator iterates through all the elements of the array, and not just to the first numItems elements.

Comment: @JB You're right of course, updated answer. With these silly toy examples its easy to be lulled into a false sense that you cannot get it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your class `NumberList` need to implement the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test {
    public class NumberList implements Iterable<Number> {
        private int numItems;
        private Number[] numbers;

        public NumberList(int size) {
            this.numbers = new Number[size];
            this.numItems = 0;
        }

        public void add(Number n) {
            this.numbers[this.numItems++] = n;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Number> iterator() {
            return Arrays.asList(numbers).iterator();
        }

    }

    public void printPairs() {

        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        NumberList numbers = new NumberList(50);
        numbers.add(4);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(6);

        for (Number n1 : numbers) {
            System.out.println(n1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question, why is it that the "implements Iterable<Number>" requires a generic type? Why can't I just leave it as Iterable? In my compiler it seems that I can leave iterator method to be raw type, but needs to put <Number> as generic type in "Implement".

Comment: @Jimster if you implemented the raw `Iterable` rather than `Iterable<Number>` then you would only be able to say `for(Object o : numbers)`, the compiler would reject `for(Number n : numbers)`

Comment: In general, even if the compiler will let you, it is never a good idea to leave anything as a raw type if there's any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [implement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) the [Iterable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). In this case, that just means you need to add a method `Iterator<T> iterator()` to your `NumberList` class. Since your list only contains numbers in this case, the generic type parameter `T` is just `Number`.