# print() function that prints the contents of each element of your list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list, element

Basically i'm trying to write a print statement that will allow me to print the elements per line as a println as the output when i run the driver.java. And for the life of me i cannot figure out how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

here is the driver.java

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String args[]){



    LList<String> s_list = new LList<String>();

    s_list.insert("New York, 8.4M");
    s_list.insert("Los Angeles 3.8M");
    s_list.insert("Chicago, 2.7M");
    s_list.insert("Houston, 2.1M");
    s_list.insert("Philadelphia, 1.55M");
    s_list.insert("Phoenix, 1.51M");
    s_list.append("San Antonio, 1.4M");
    s_list.append("San Diego, 1.35M");
    s_list.append("Dallas, 1.25M");
    s_list.append("San Jose, 0.998M");
    s_list.append("Austin, 0.88M");
    s_list.append("Indianapolis, 0.84M");
    s_list.append("Jacksonville, 0.84M");
    s_list.append("San Francisco, 0.83M");
    s_list.append("Columbus, 0.82M");
    s_list.append("Charlotte, 0.79M");

    s_list.print();
    s_list.moveToPos(3);
    s_list.remove();
    s_list.print();
    s_list.moveToEnd();
    s_list.remove();
    s_list.print();
    s_list.moveToStart();
    s_list.remove();
    s_list.remove();
    s_list.print();
    s_list.clear();
    s_list.print();


}

}
```

and I have a java file named LList.java

where I am trying to write a print method where it will print() function that prints the contents of  each element of your list; print one element per line.

```
public void print { 

}
```

So, How will i print the elements in "s_list" line per line as output.

Any help is appreciated.

---

UPDATE: I am going to post Llist.java,list.java & link.java here

Llist.java

```
 /** Linked list implementation */ 

 class LList<E> implements List<E> { 
 private Link<E> head; // Pointer to list header 
 private Link<E> tail; // Pointer to last element 
protected Link<E> curr; // Access to current element 
 private int cnt; // Size of list 
 /** Constructors */ 
 LList(int size) { this(); } // Constructor -- Ignore size 
 LList() { 
 curr = tail = head = new Link<E>(null); // Create header 
  cnt = 0; 
 } 
/** Remove all elements */ 
public void clear() { 
head.setNext(null); // Drop access to links 
curr = tail = head = new Link<E>(null); // Create header 
cnt = 0; 
} 
/** Insert "it" at current position */ 
public void insert(E it) { 
curr.setNext(new Link<E>(it, curr.next())); 
if (tail == curr) tail = curr.next(); // New tail 
cnt++; 
} 
/** Append "it" to list */ 
public void append(E it) { 
tail = tail.setNext(new Link<E>(it, null)); 
cnt++; 
} 
/** Remove and return current element */ 
public E remove() { 
if (curr.next() == null) return null; // Nothing to remove 
 E it = curr.next().element(); // Remember value 
 if (tail == curr.next()) tail = curr; // Removed last 
curr.setNext(curr.next().next()); // Remove from list 
cnt--; // Decrement count 
return it; // Return value 
} 
/** Set curr at list start */ 
public void moveToStart() 
{ curr = head; } 

/** Set curr at list end */ 
public void moveToEnd() 
{ curr = tail; } 
/** Move curr one step left; no change if now at front */ 
public void prev() { 
if (curr == head) return; // No previous element 
Link<E> temp = head; 
// March down list until we find the previous element 
while (temp.next() != curr) temp = temp.next(); 
curr = temp; 
} 
/** Move curr one step right; no change if now at end */ 
public void next() 
{ if (curr != tail) curr = curr.next(); } 
/** @return List length */ 
public int length() { return cnt; } 
/** @return The position of the current element */ 
public int currPos() { 
    Link<E> temp = head; 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; curr != temp; i++) 
        temp = temp.next(); 
    return i; 
} 
/** Move down list to "pos" position */ 
public void moveToPos(int pos) { 
    assert (pos>=0) && (pos<=cnt) : "Position out of range"; 
    curr = head; 
    for(int i=0; i<pos; i++) curr = curr.next(); 
} 
/** @return Current element value */ 
public E getValue() { 
    if(curr.next() == null) return null; 
    return curr.next().element(); 
}

public void print()
{

}   

}
```

List.java

```
/** List ADT */ 
public interface List<E> { 
    /** Remove all contents from the list, so it is once again 
empty. Client is responsible for reclaiming storage 
used by the list elements. */ 
    public void clear(); 
    /** Insert an element at the current location. The client 
must ensure that the list�s capacity is not exceeded. 
@param item The element to be inserted. */ 
    public void insert(E item); 
    /** Append an element at the end of the list. The client 
must ensure that the list�s capacity is not exceeded. 
@param item The element to be appended. */ 
    public void append(E item); 
    /** Remove and return the current element. 
@return The element that was removed. */ 
    public E remove(); 
    /** Set the current position to the start of the list */ 
    public void moveToStart(); 
    /** Set the current position to the end of the list */ 
    public void moveToEnd(); 
    /** Move the current position one step left. No change 
if already at beginning. */ 
    public void prev(); 
    /** Move the current position one step right. No change 
if already at end. */ 
    public void next(); 
    /** @return The number of elements in the list. */ 
    public int length(); 
    /** @return The position of the current element. */ 
    public int currPos(); 
    /** Set current position. 
@param pos The position to make current. */ 
    public void moveToPos(int pos); 
    /** @return The current element. */ 
    public E getValue(); 
}
```

Link.java

```
/** Singly linked list node */ 
class Link<E> { 

    private E element; // Value for this node 
    private Link<E> next; // Pointer to next node in list 
    // Constructors 
    Link(E it, Link<E> nextval) 
    { element = it; next = nextval; } 
    Link(Link<E> nextval) { next = nextval; } 
    Link<E> next() { return next; } // Return next field 
    Link<E> setNext(Link<E> nextval) // Set next field 
    { return next = nextval; } // Return element field 
    E element() { return element; } // Set element field 
    E setElement(E it) { return element = it; } 
}
```

Comment: How about `s_list.foreach(System.out::println)`? Without posting the code for `LList`, or at least its declaration, there's not much we can help you with.

Answer (score 2):

We will need to see inside the class of LList.java... but for now i am going to assume LList extends List [or ArrayList, etc..]

```
public void print
{
     for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)  //this really depends on how you store your list
          System.out.println(this.get(i));
}
```

This all depends on how your LList.java looks though... [this.size()] refers to the List or ArrayList class [if you extended it...].

If you are not extending List or something along those lines, you could always do:

```
public void print
{
     for(int i = 0; i < storingArray.size(); /*or .length*/ i++)
          System.out.println(storingArray.get(i)); /*or storingArray[i]*/
}
```

But as always, you could take the easy way and just do:

```
list.foreach(System.out::println); //must have Java 8.
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the guidance. I have have added the codes for the other core java files i have part of this project. please take a look at it and see if you can figure out what needs to be changed since I don't have a method Size in the other .java i have done.

Answer (score 0):

Revised Answer based on your comments:

```
public void print() {
        Link<E> currentNode  = head; //Sets starting node to first node in list
        while (currentNode != tail) { //Checks if current node is equal to last node
            System.out.println(currentNode.element()); //Prints currentNodes's element
            currentNode = currentNode.next(); //Sets currentNode to next node in list
        }
        System.out.println(tail.element()); //Prints last node in list      
}
```

Note: Some of your comments in  you `Link<E>`code don't match what your functions are actually doing.

Comment: s_list cannot be resolved to a variable is the error i'm getting.

Comment: Is the for loop within your print() function? Are you passing s_list into the function?

Comment: I've reviewed the code more and posted a revised answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: "Can only iterate to an array or an instance "is the error i get on the print method now.

Comment: You can either change your list to implement Iterable, which will allow the for loop to work, or you can attempt the following way. Start at the head node in your linked list and retrieve its value (getValue() function you created). Then go to the node it points at and repeat. System.out.print() each value you retrieve until next node points to null;

Comment: Implementing Iterable was explained in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050379/implementing-the-iterable-interface)

Comment: I am still having issues with this.

Comment: This is what I'm have so far .... `code`public void print() {
    // for (E element : this) {
     //    System.out.println(element);
     //}
     
     Link<E> temp;
     temp = head;
     while (temp.next() != tail)
     {
      System.out.println(temp.element());
     }
     
     } `code`

Comment: This is what i Have so far for it based on what your telling me.   `public void print() {
  
  Link<E> temp = head; 
  System.out.println(this.getValue());
      
  }`     That seems to print the elements but not properly it's missing elements in between

Comment: @mat Please check my revised answer. You may need to change my code for situations where `tail` node is null (empty list)